# Dotnet new console returning error on run

Tags: c#, .net, exception, unhandled

I have tried to run "dotnet new console" in any terminal a few times and each time it returns an error:

```
Unhandled exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Trist\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v7.0.101' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.Commands.BaseCommand.CreateEnvironmentSettings(GlobalArgs args, ParseResult parseResult)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.Commands.BaseCommand`1.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.Commands.BaseCommand`1.Invoke(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Parser.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__17_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<UseParseDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I have allowed permissions to every available user in the file settings, re-installed and repaired dotnet. I've been at it for a few hours and cant seem to find anyone else with the same or similar issue so have made little to no progress in overcoming the problem.. any and all help is much appreciated

Comment: have you tried in some other directory?

Comment: I have tried multiple different directories with no success as if yet. Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. The security settings inside one of the folders wasn't saving after being changed, after a restart of the computer and a careful scan through everything again i have resolved the issue.